# i cant see images in production in my laravel website

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i deployed my Laravel website in a domain name at hostinger.ae , everything was working successfully
[image: first domain]
, then i tried to deploy the same files in a different domain name

[image: second domain]

i changed the file .env from :

```
APP_URL=http://ohp-dubai.com/public
```

to :

```
APP_URL=http://cliqlead.com/public
```

i use : `src="{{ asset('storage/icons/cliqlead-logo.png') }}"`
for viewing the image ,it works with the first domain , but the second one , it doesn't work

what should i do or change ?

Comment: How does the generated markup look like? Does it reference the folder where your images are stored? Also, how is this question related to MySQL?

Comment: Did you check/inspect the image elements to make sure their `src` is fine? Maybe running `php artisan config:cache` can help

Comment: does project files are saved on the same server?

Comment: guys ! the project files and images saved on the same server and also it reference to the folder where my images are stored !

Comment: i just copied and paste the same files and folders to and other domain with changing the APP_URL , that's just what i did !

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If the markup that is generated references the files properly, and the server configuration is sound, but the images are still not shown, then you need to dive deeper. What's the HTTP response code for the images? What does your server's error log tell you about the problem?

Comment: @brombeer i checked the the url image is : http://cliqlead.com/public/storage/32/61e7dc770c85f_villa.jpg , and yes my image exist in this folder so the source is true but it give me 404 | not found :\

Comment: `public` should not appear in any URL, it should be the "DocumentRoot" of your webserver/vhost.